# Proxy radar found in apache logs file

Tags: php, apache, logging, server

I was reading the logs of the Apache server and I was shocked by seeing these logs!

```
[Sun Oct 25 06:44:48.922248 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17635] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 25 06:44:48.922322 2015] [core:notice] [pid 17635] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Oct 25 06:52:03.432156 2015] [:error] [pid 12247] [client 185.25.151.159:52483] script '/var/www/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Oct 25 10:04:07.474749 2015] [:error] [pid 12246] [client 95.213.177.126:26970] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Sun Oct 25 13:30:45.499151 2015] [:error] [pid 12249] [client 95.213.177.124:12337] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Sun Oct 25 14:56:17.907266 2015] [core:error] [pid 12247] [client 204.232.231.193:42272] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.1
[Sun Oct 25 16:47:51.671775 2015] [:error] [pid 13152] [client 95.213.177.122:22221] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Sun Oct 25 20:05:20.347574 2015] [:error] [pid 12250] [client 95.213.177.126:26093] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Sun Oct 25 20:12:20.573716 2015] [:error] [pid 12247] [client 195.211.154.57:59906] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Oct 25 20:12:20.925707 2015] [:error] [pid 12246] [client 195.211.154.57:59982] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Oct 25 20:12:21.286692 2015] [:error] [pid 14778] [client 195.211.154.57:60061] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Oct 25 20:12:21.653284 2015] [:error] [pid 12248] [client 195.211.154.57:60129] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Oct 25 23:40:01.996372 2015] [:error] [pid 13152] [client 95.213.177.125:11645] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Mon Oct 26 02:51:58.571464 2015] [:error] [pid 12247] [client 185.49.14.190:56375] script '/var/www/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Oct 26 03:06:19.339766 2015] [:error] [pid 12246] [client 95.213.177.125:57675] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Mon Oct 26 05:40:34.837617 2015] [:error] [pid 12249] [client 212.26.4.140:45817] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: fileToUpload in /var/www/upload.php on line 16, referer: http://MyServerIPAddress/index.html
[Mon Oct 26 05:40:34.845077 2015] [:error] [pid 12249] [client 212.26.4.140:45817] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: fileToUpload in /var/www/upload.php on line 36, referer: http://MyServerIPAddress/index.html
[Mon Oct 26 06:35:27.184473 2015] [:error] [pid 12247] [client 95.213.177.123:49908] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Mon Oct 26 10:00:38.818189 2015] [:error] [pid 12250] [client 95.213.177.124:13503] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Mon Oct 26 13:31:03.088079 2015] [:error] [pid 12246] [client 95.213.177.126:29119] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Mon Oct 26 17:00:20.614876 2015] [:error] [pid 12247] [client 95.213.177.126:50712] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Mon Oct 26 20:29:44.660822 2015] [:error] [pid 12250] [client 95.213.177.126:1817] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Tue Oct 27 00:01:58.744948 2015] [:error] [pid 14778] [client 95.213.177.122:21314] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Tue Oct 27 01:11:03.468846 2015] [:error] [pid 18984] [client 185.25.148.240:59900] script '/var/www/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Oct 27 03:30:14.778881 2015] [:error] [pid 18983] [client 95.213.177.125:18166] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Tue Oct 27 07:03:54.964307 2015] [:error] [pid 13152] [client 95.213.177.125:6661] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Tue Oct 27 10:29:50.276896 2015] [:error] [pid 12246] [client 95.213.177.124:61095] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Tue Oct 27 13:53:21.732290 2015] [:error] [pid 14778] [client 95.213.177.123:60280] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Tue Oct 27 17:21:02.887146 2015] [:error] [pid 12248] [client 95.213.177.125:63152] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Tue Oct 27 20:50:02.216260 2015] [:error] [pid 18983] [client 95.213.177.123:36963] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Tue Oct 27 21:14:02.927072 2015] [:error] [pid 12249] [client 185.25.148.240:60127] script '/var/www/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat    
[Wed Oct 28 00:14:25.724517 2015] [:error] [pid 12250] [client 95.213.177.123:49920] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Wed Oct 28 03:44:31.131853 2015] [:error] [pid 12246] [client 95.213.177.124:43972] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Wed Oct 28 07:10:14.870620 2015] [:error] [pid 18983] [client 95.213.177.122:64165] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Wed Oct 28 10:41:34.266047 2015] [:error] [pid 12249] [client 95.213.177.122:7384] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Wed Oct 28 14:04:14.227135 2015] [:error] [pid 13152] [client 95.213.177.122:51171] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Wed Oct 28 16:20:24.056612 2015] [:error] [pid 12247] [client 91.196.50.33:37592] script '/var/www/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Wed Oct 28 17:24:12.731783 2015] [:error] [pid 12250] [client 95.213.177.126:63964] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Wed Oct 28 21:01:47.135810 2015] [:error] [pid 12246] [client 95.213.177.122:46135] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Thu Oct 29 00:26:45.812360 2015] [:error] [pid 12249] [client 95.213.177.123:4377] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Thu Oct 29 03:51:35.202020 2015] [:error] [pid 13152] [client 95.213.177.123:5403] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Thu Oct 29 07:16:27.154161 2015] [:error] [pid 14778] [client 95.213.177.125:60001] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Thu Oct 29 10:47:57.392473 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17635] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Oct 29 10:47:58.276766 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10744] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal     operations
[Thu Oct 29 10:47:58.276856 2015] [core:notice] [pid 10744] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Oct 29 10:48:00.183820 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10744] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Oct 29 10:48:01.268504 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11109] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 29 10:48:01.268593 2015] [core:notice] [pid 11109] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Oct 29 10:53:55.208328 2015] [:error] [pid 11117] [client 95.213.177.126:24617] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Thu Oct 29 12:05:44.568022 2015] [:error] [pid 11116] [client 185.25.151.159:44881] script '/var/www/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 14:23:29.206838 2015] [:error] [pid 11113] [client     95.213.177.122:51825] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Thu Oct 29 17:46:40.522593 2015] [:error] [pid 11648] [client 95.213.177.123:6131] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Thu Oct 29 21:19:33.442885 2015] [:error] [pid 11642] [client 95.213.177.126:29530] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:04.453806 2015] [:error] [pid 11114] [client     195.211.154.57:60044] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:04.717870 2015] [:error] [pid 11643] [client 195.211.154.57:60066] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:04.982542 2015] [:error] [pid 11117] [client 195.211.154.57:60089] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:05.234578 2015] [:error] [pid 11115] [client 195.211.154.57:60114] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:05.482102 2015] [:error] [pid 11116] [client 195.211.154.57:60141] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:05.740567 2015] [:error] [pid 11113] [client 195.211.154.57:60161] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:05.993417 2015] [:error] [pid 11648] [client 195.211.154.57:60182] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:06.254748 2015] [:error] [pid 11642] [client 195.211.154.57:60210] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:06.501836 2015] [:error] [pid 11114] [client 195.211.154.57:60231] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:06.753228 2015] [:error] [pid 11643] [client 195.211.154.57:60252] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:07.015822 2015] [:error] [pid 11117] [client 195.211.154.57:60276] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:07.278555 2015] [:error] [pid 11115] [client 195.211.154.57:60304] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:07.529478 2015] [:error] [pid 11116] [client 195.211.154.57:60329] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:07.777850 2015] [:error] [pid 11113] [client 195.211.154.57:60351] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:08.022832 2015] [:error] [pid 11648] [client 195.211.154.57:60371] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:08.268446 2015] [:error] [pid 11642] [client 195.211.154.57:60393] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:08.524456 2015] [:error] [pid 11114] [client 195.211.154.57:60412] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:08.770056 2015] [:error] [pid 11643] [client 195.211.154.57:60434] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:09.031264 2015] [:error] [pid 11117] [client 195.211.154.57:60450] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:09.286882 2015] [:error] [pid 11115] [client 195.211.154.57:60473] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:09.537999 2015] [:error] [pid 11116] [client 195.211.154.57:60494] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:09.796330 2015] [:error] [pid 11113] [client 195.211.154.57:60512] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:10.047986 2015] [:error] [pid 11648] [client 195.211.154.57:60537] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:10.294042 2015] [:error] [pid 11642] [client 195.211.154.57:60560] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:10.549803 2015] [:error] [pid 11114] [client 195.211.154.57:60581] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:10.808650 2015] [:error] [pid 11643] [client 195.211.154.57:60604] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:11.056997 2015] [:error] [pid 11117] [client 195.211.154.57:60625] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:11.301379 2015] [:error] [pid 11115] [client 195.211.154.57:60652] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:11.547697 2015] [:error] [pid 11116] [client 195.211.154.57:60668] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:11.797300 2015] [:error] [pid 11113] [client 195.211.154.57:60693] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:12.056947 2015] [:error] [pid 11648] [client 195.211.154.57:60717] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:12.312125 2015] [:error] [pid 11642] [client 195.211.154.57:60737] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:12.560742 2015] [:error] [pid 11114] [client 195.211.154.57:60757] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:12.813413 2015] [:error] [pid 11643] [client 195.211.154.57:60776] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:13.065100 2015] [:error] [pid 11117] [client 195.211.154.57:60801] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:13.320162 2015] [:error] [pid 11115] [client 195.211.154.57:60824] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:13.569527 2015] [:error] [pid 11116] [client 195.211.154.57:60848] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:13.814746 2015] [:error] [pid 11113] [client 195.211.154.57:60871] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:14.066743 2015] [:error] [pid 11648] [client 195.211.154.57:60887] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:14.326231 2015] [:error] [pid 11642] [client 195.211.154.57:60915] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:14.585975 2015] [:error] [pid 11114] [client 195.211.154.57:60936] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:14.844341 2015] [:error] [pid 11643] [client 195.211.154.57:60956] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 29 21:40:15.095272 2015] [:error] [pid 11117] [client 195.211.154.57:60981] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Oct 30 00:47:05.284551 2015] [:error] [pid 11115] [client 95.213.177.125:26477] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Fri Oct 30 04:09:19.403419 2015] [:error] [pid 11116] [client 95.213.177.122:31198] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Fri Oct 30 07:42:17.527746 2015] [:error] [pid 11648] [client 95.213.177.124:59115] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Fri Oct 30 10:13:59.016697 2015] [:error] [pid 11642] [client 91.196.50.33:36603] script '/var/www/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Oct 30 11:06:15.666434 2015] [:error] [pid 11114] [client 95.213.177.123:16988] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Fri Oct 30 14:28:18.705393 2015] [:error] [pid 11643] [client 95.213.177.124:53349] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Fri Oct 30 17:58:00.532339 2015] [:error] [pid 11115] [client 95.213.177.122:53827] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Fri Oct 30 21:12:46.869377 2015] [:error] [pid 11116] [client 95.213.177.122:54578] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Sat Oct 31 00:35:01.994847 2015] [:error] [pid 11113] [client 95.213.177.123:2596] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Sat Oct 31 02:24:36.644160 2015] [:error] [pid 11648] [client 185.25.148.240:58843] script '/var/www/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sat Oct 31 04:05:26.854168 2015] [:error] [pid 11642] [client 95.213.177.123:5184] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Sat Oct 31 04:43:12.015411 2015] [:error] [pid 11114] [client 91.196.50.33:46098] script '/var/www/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sat Oct 31 07:25:14.509690 2015] [:error] [pid 11117] [client 95.213.177.123:3185] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Sat Oct 31 10:15:58.489698 2015] [:error] [pid 11115] [client 5.8.66.115:54407] script '/var/www/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sat Oct 31 10:46:10.183445 2015] [:error] [pid 11116] [client 95.213.177.122:28801] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
```

Should I be concerned with these logs? Do they indicate any kind of attack?

The ip trying to do all that stuff is coming from Poland. How can I ban this ip and remove all of the files he/she put on my server? I am using digitalocean service; is that related?

Comment: Looks like a simple scan. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897993/am-i-being-hacked

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar traffic. My guess is someone is trying to exploit some kind of bug. I saw [this](http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/Proxy/) sample code. See @joveha's comment.